# Setup Pulsar transaction coordinator in Kubernetes setup

Tags: kubernetes, apache-pulsar

How to setup Apache Pulsar transaction coordinator in Kubernetes setup? I couldn't see much docs on this, though I could modify the `broker.conf` configmap unsure if that even works.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction coordinator is a part of the broker, I think you just enable the transaction feature in the broker configmap is ok